# How can I set setContentType("text/html") or setContentType("text/plain") dynamically

Tags: java, html, servlets, text, mime-types

I need to modify the code that read a text file, in a dynamically to read text or html files.

Now the code use only

> response.setContentType("text/plain");

because the file is saved in text format. But I would like to save in html format to manage all tag and have a better view, but If I modify in

> response.setContentType("text/html");

all file saved as text have a wrong viewer

My code is:

```java
package uk.co.mycode.fax.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import uk.co.mycode.fax.dao.mycodeFaxDAO;
import uk.co.mycode.fax.domain.Image;
import uk.co.morpheus.logging.Logger;

public class FaxImageRequest
  extends HttpServlet
{
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { performTask(request, response); }

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { performTask(request, response); }

  public void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String url = request.getParameter("U");
    if (url == null || url.length() < 1) {
      url = request.getParameter("URL");
    }
    Logger.log(4, getClass().getName(), "<**** Entered FaxImageRequest (" + url + ") ****>");
    try {
      Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
      String userId = "";
      if (cookies != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          if (cookies[i].getName().equals("IMPS3IAuserid")) {
            userId = cookies[i].getValue();

            break;
          } 
        } 
      }
      if (userId.length() < 1) {
        userId = "NOT LOGGED ON";
      }

      mycodeFaxDAO dao = mycodeFaxDAO.getInstance();

      Image image = dao.getImage(url);

      Logger.log(4, getClass().getName(), "Image: " + image);

      if (image != null) {
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        if (image.type.toLowerCase().startsWith("f")) {
            response.setContentType("image/tiff");
        } else {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

               response.setContentType("text/plain");

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------      
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < image.bytes.length; ) { out.write(image.bytes, i, (image.bytes.length - i > 4096) ? 4096 : (image.bytes.length - i)); i += 4096; }

        dao.updateImageArchive(userId, request.getParameter("U"));
      } else {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<HTML>");
        pw.println("<BODY>");
        pw.println("<B>No image found</B>");
        pw.println("</BODY>");
        pw.println("</HTML>");
        pw.close();
      } 
    } catch (Throwable th) {
      Logger.log(1, getClass().getName(), "Error during image read or update:" + th.getMessage());
      th.printStackTrace();
    } 

    Logger.log(4, getClass().getName(), "<**** Finished FaxImageRequest ****>");
  }
}
```

I tried to write this:

```java
if (response.getContentType() == null) {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
              } else {
                    response.setContentType("text/plain");
              }
```

but it is always null.
Thanks for the support.

Comment: How would you know whether the file is a text file or an HTML file?

Comment: This is my problem. I need to know before. All new files will be html, but all old files are text

Comment: Question doesn't have enough information for us to help with that. It does have a lot of unrelated code, confusing the situation. Anyway, do the "files" have names, e.g. with extensions like `.txt` and `.html`? Can't even see anything representing a "file" in that code, unless `Image` is a tiff/text/html "file", in which case it is a very badly named class.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer, if I may bring up your "hosting platform" - is that such settings are usually changed in the hosting platform.  I have hosted three different web domains with GCS (Google Cloud Server) because it is (mostly) free.

In Google Cloud, when you save a file, generally it will recognize what type of file you have save (Content-Type) based on the file's extension - '.txt' or '.html'. The Content-Type setting can be changed in Google's bucket file explorer GUI using a mouse.  It may also be changed manually at the command line using the GSUTIL command line program.

You may make calls to GSUTIL from Java by using Java's shell execution libraries (the Java Standard library routines for calling UNIX Shell commands). This is what I do...

... But you may even download Google's Java Jar files to access GCS and make Java based calls to GCS for doing things like changing the content type of a storage bucket file....

If you were using.MSFT Azure, or GoDaddy or something else this would be different.